# Two overloaded methods to move an e-mail message to another mailbox folder

Tags: c#, null

I have an API for managing an email mailbox.  There is a class called `Message`, and it has two `Move` overloads:

```
/// <summary>
/// Move this message to the mailbox folder whose path is provided.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="toFolderPath">The path to the mailbox folder to which this message will be moved.</param>
/// <param name="createFolder">If true, the destination folder will be created first if it doesn't exist.</param>
/// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">
/// <para>An exception will be thrown if this message does not reside in a mailbox because
/// only messages in mailboxes can be moved between folders.  Use <see cref="ContainingFolder"/> to determine if
/// the message resides within a mailbox and folder; that value will be null if it does not.</para>
/// <para>An exception will be thrown if the destination folder does not exist and if the provided <paramref name="createFolder"/> is false.</para>
/// </exception>
public void Move(string toFolderPath, bool createFolder)
{
    ValidateMoveCopy();
    Move(GetCreateFolder(toFolderPath, createFolder));
}

/// <summary>
/// Move this message to the provided mailbox folder.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="toFolder">The mailbox folder to which this message will be moved.</param>
/// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">An exception will be thrown if this message does not reside in a mailbox because
/// only messages in mailboxes can be moved between folders.  Use <see cref="ContainingFolder"/> to determine if
/// the message resides within a mailbox and folder; that value will be null if it does not.</exception>
public void Move(MailboxFolder toFolder)
{
    ValidateMoveCopy();
    ParentMailbox.MoveMessage(this, toFolder);
}
```

The first overload will retrieve the mailbox folder or create it if it doesn't yet exist, but only if the `createFolder` argument is `true`; then it will just call the second overload.

What I'd like to avoid is calling the `ValidateMoveCopy` twice when the first overload is used (once in that method, and once in the second overload); however, I don't want `GetCreateFolder` to be called in the first method if validation fails.

Here are `GetCreateFolder` and `ValidateMoveCopy`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Return the folder with the provided path, if it exists, from the parent mailbox,
/// or else create it if it should be created based on <paramref name="createIfMissing"/>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="withFolderPath"></param>
/// <param name="createIfMissing"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private MailboxFolder GetCreateFolder(string withFolderPath, bool createIfMissing)
{
    if (createIfMissing)
    {
        return ParentMailbox.CreateFolder(withFolderPath); // create or retrieve if existing.
    }
    else // folder won't be created if it doesn't exist.
    {
        var ret = ParentMailbox.GetFolder(withFolderPath);
        if (ret == null) throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(@"The folder ""{0}"" does not exist in mailbox ""{1}"" and will not be created.", withFolderPath, ParentMailbox.Name));
        return ret;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Validate this message for a "move" or "copy" operation, and throw an exception if not valid.
/// </summary>
private void ValidateMoveCopy()
{
    if (ParentMailbox == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("This message does not reside in a mailbox and cannot be moved or copied.");
}
```

Is there a good way to do this?  Since both overloads are public, I don't want to do something like add a `bool isAlreadyValidated` to the second overload.  I could use a private field:

```
/// <summary>
/// True only if a move operation is underway and it has already been validated.
/// </summary>
private bool _isValidatedForMove = false;
```

and use it like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Move this message to the mailbox folder whose path is provided.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="toFolderPath">The path to the mailbox folder to which this message will be moved.</param>
/// <param name="createFolder">If true, the destination folder will be created first if it doesn't exist.</param>
/// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">
/// <para>An exception will be thrown if this message does not reside in a mailbox because
/// only messages in mailboxes can be moved between folders.  Use <see cref="ContainingFolder"/> to determine if
/// the message resides within a mailbox and folder; that value will be null if it does not.</para>
/// <para>An exception will be thrown if the destination folder does not exist and if the provided <paramref name="createFolder"/> is false.</para>
/// </exception>
public void Move(string toFolderPath, bool createFolder)
{
    ValidateMoveCopy();
    _isValidatedForMove = true;
    Move(GetCreateFolder(toFolderPath, createFolder));
    _isValidatedForMove = false;
}

/// <summary>
/// Move this message to the provided mailbox folder.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="toFolder">The mailbox folder to which this message will be moved.</param>
/// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">An exception will be thrown if this message does not reside in a mailbox because
/// only messages in mailboxes can be moved between folders.  Use <see cref="ContainingFolder"/> to determine if
/// the message resides within a mailbox and folder; that value will be null if it does not.</exception>
public void Move(MailboxFolder toFolder)
{
    if(!_isValidatedForMove) ValidateMoveCopy();
    ParentMailbox.MoveMessage(this, toFolder);
}
```

But that feels kind of like a code smell for some reason.  I welcome any thoughts or suggestions.  By the way, I'm aware this code isn't thread safe.

Comment: @DrProgrammer If you have suggestions to improve the code, then please write an answer. Critiquing the code in comments is not appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best option would be to introduce a third, private method:

```
private void Move(MailboxFolder toFolder, bool requiresValidation)
{
    if (requiresValidation)
    {
        ValidateMoveCopy();
    }
    ParentMailbox.MoveMessage(this, toFolder);
}
```

Then your other methods just call that one.

```
public void Move(MailboxFolder toFolder)
{
    Move(toFolder, true);
}

public void Move(string toFolderPath, bool createFolder)
{
    ValidateMoveCopy();
    MailboxFolder toFolder = GetOrCreateFolder(toFolderPath, createFolder);
    Move(toFolder, false);
}
```

I renamed `GetCreateFolder` to `GetOrCreateFolder` which is slightly easier to read IMO. I've also introduced a variable for `toFolder` as I don't like lines of code that do 2 things.

Edit:

Short and concise methods are brilliant and a very good thing to aim for. However, consider your method at a glance:

```
Move(GetCreateFolder(toFolderPath, createFolder));
```

How easy is it to spot the side effect there (possibly creating a new folder) vs my version:

```
MailboxFolder toFolder = GetOrCreateFolder(toFolderPath, createFolder);
Move(toFolder, false);
```

It's a stylistic thing without doubt and if you prefer the brevity then that's absolutely fine. I should have been more explicit about that being a preference thing rather than a rule!

Comment: Thank you, this is great.  To your point about lines that do multiple things, I'm always looking to keep methods to as few lines as possible as a rule.  Can you elaborate on why (other than ease of debugging) multiple lines is better than one line?

Comment: @roryap - added an update for you!